# Junit to test Java EE Application Client

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, glassfish, javabeans

I've created an Java EE application on Glassfish and it's deployed and run successfully.
However when I try to use junit to test the Application Client module, It says
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
I tried with many ways:

```
Hashtable env=new Hashtable();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
Context c = new InitialContext(env);
Object remote = c.lookup("java:comp/env/BookStore");
```

and it says cant not find class com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory

I'm looking for this issue for 2 days but I've got no hope :(
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume that you seen the [EJB FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html) for Glassfish. It answers the multitude of questions folks have on how to connect applications to Glassfish.

You also don't mention which version of GF you're using, and that can be important since they use different jars and such.

Comment: I'm using glassfish 3. When I set the J2EE Application as main project and run it with F6. It's fine. However, I want to run the Junit test package instead. It says can not find jndi. This is obvious because maybe It ignore some steps to deploy the app. But I dont know how to fix it to run junit

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure jar file containing `com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory` is in your classpath. The jar is provided by Glassfish.